# '$(...).DataTable is not a function' error

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to apply the jQuery DataTables library but I am getting an error:

> $(...).DataTable is not a function

Please look and help me out. I've tried in numerous ways to change the scripts loaded. I've changed tags and the jQuery version too.

```js
function Succes() {

    $("#tbl").DataTable();
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Class</th>
       
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblbody">`
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're only loading the DataTables Responsive *extension*. You also need to include the main DataTables library in the page before you include that extension.

Comment: i have included the main DataTables library before Responsive Same issue

Comment: Firstly please edit the question to include your updated code. Secondly, are you certain that the paths to your scrips are correct?

Comment: Your issue is that the DataTables library is not being loaded correctly. What you have shown should work absolutely fine, and without a demonstrable version of the problem no one can really offer you any further help

Comment: Tnx For u r replay though i know its DataTables library is not being loaded.thing is where the things are going wrong.could you help me